# Managing Multi-project ivy dependencies

Tags: sbt

I have a multi-project build with sub-projects `foo` and `bar`. `foo` depends on `bar`.

`foo` and `bar` are both intended to be used via Ivy dependencies. Thus, `foo` has a library dependency on `bar`. However, in my multi-project build, I don't want to use Ivy dependencies. Rather, I want to look in specified directories for `foo` and `bar` and build with the versions in those directories. I essentially want to tell SBT, "The Ivy dependency you're looking for is actually this SBT project in this directory."

I want this all to be handled by SBT automatically. That is, I don't want to have to go into `bar` and execute SBT "publish-local" for this to work.

For reference, my multi-project has `build.scala` with the following:

```
lazy val bar = project in file("bar")
lazy val foo = (project in file("foo")).dependsOn(bar)
lazy val myProject = (project in file(".")).dependsOn(foo, bar)
```

This obviously handles classPath dependencies but does not actually use the project in `bar` for the `foo` Ivy dependency.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you mean by 'treating the bar project as the Ivy dependency'. If you use `dependsOn`, then code in `bar` should be available to code that wants to import it in `foo`. What more are you looking to do? Package `bar` and import it as a JAR file? Something else?

Comment: Apologies for being unclear. What I mean is that `bar` is published to an ivy repo and that `foo` has a library dependency on `bar`. While `dependsOn` works fine for the actual Scala dependency, if I'm developing and bump the version of `bar` (and don't publish it), then want `foo` to use this version of `bar`, it doesn't work because SBT complains that it can't find the ivy repo (even though the code is right there in "bar"!). It does work if I do a `publish-local` in `bar`, but it seems like SBT should be able to handle this automatically without having to manually do the publishing.

Comment: This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but what happens if you replace `dependsOn(bar)` with `dependsOn(bar % "compile->publish-local")`? If that doesn't work, you can define a custom task that first executes publish-local and then compiles `foo`.

Comment: Unfortunately changing `dependsOn` as described didn't work. Nice idea though! As far as I can tell, publish-local is the only way. There is a github issue on sbt from 14 days ago so perhaps a better solution will present itself!  https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2777